# Can quadratics with complex coefficients have more than two roots?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, roots

So I came across this quadratic, $z^2(1-2i)+6iz+-2i-1$, and used the quadratic equation to get its roots, $z_1 = \frac{2-i}{5}, z_2 = 2-i$. However, when I used this in a limit it came out differently.
$$\lim_{z \to \frac{2-i}{5}} (z - \frac{2-i}{5})(\frac{2}{z^2(1-2i)+6iz+-2i-1)} = \frac{-i}{2}$$
$$\lim_{z \to \frac{2-i}{5}} (z - \frac{2-i}{5})(\frac{2}{(z - \frac{2-i}{5})(z - 2 + i)}) = -1 -\frac{-i}{2}$$

This has lead me to believe the quadratic may have three roots. Not sure though, just can't see why else they wouldn't be equal - hoping someone can shed some light.

[See limits calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZH5X.png) 
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRp8i.png)

Thanks, Jack

Comment: You will have made some mistake somewhere. It is a nice theorem of complex analysis that every $n$-degree polynomial has exactly $n$ roots, up to multiplicity, so in particular a quadratic (degree $2$) cannot have more than $2$ roots

Comment: the \left( and \right) make the parenthesis look better.

Comment: @Somos Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but the two denominators in the limit are not the same quadratic polynomial. Anyhow that a quadratic polynomial has two possibly equal roots is a sure bet.

Comment: @Somos: +1. You can write that into an answer.

Comment: @user1046533 Thanks! I did as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\,az^2+bz+c=0\,$ has roots $\,z_1\,$ and $\,z_2\,$, then
$\, az^2+bz+c=a(z−z_1)(z−z_2)\,$ factors. Notice carefully the
need to include the factor $\,a\,$ which you forgot about and
this is your mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if we work in $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{R} \oplus i\mathbb{R} \oplus j\mathbb{R}$ where $ij = ji$ and $i^2=-1$ yet $j^2=1$ then we can have quadratic equations involving complex coefficients with more or less than two solutions. Most of this comes from $(1-j)(1+j)=1-j^2=0$ despite the fact that $1 \pm j \neq 0$. Let's see, an explicit example would be:
$$ i^2z^2-1 = (iz-1)(iz+1) = (iz-j)(iz+j) = 0$$
for $z = \pm i$ and $z = \pm ij$ here $i,j$ are independent, so these are four distinct solutions to this quadratic equation.

Now, can you find 4 solutions to a quadratic equations just using complex numbers alone ? No.

Comment: Cool! Hoping to study in more dimensions, do you know where in maths this stuff pops up?

Comment: Nowhere in the standard curriculum so far as I know. I stumbled into this stuff in a project with students about 10 years ago. Not in regular coursework. It was a central topic in mainstream math about 120 years ago.